# Positioning dynamic content from Django models via Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to make a personal blog template, and I'm stuck at a page which shows all posts' previews. In this page, there are two columns, `#content-column-left` and `#content-column-right`, and the previews should be placed on one of the columns based on the height of the columns (the shorter column receives the next post preview). I've been trying to do it via JavaScript, with an array containing "dummy" data:

```
function processPosts() {
    var cleft = document.getElementById('content-column-left');
    var cright = document.getElementById('content-column-right');

    for (var i = 0; i < testeVector.length; i++) {
        var preview = document.createElement('div');
        preview.className = 'post-preview';
        var conteudo = postsVector[i];
        var aux = document.createElement('h1');
        aux.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content.title))
        preview.appendChild(aux);
        preview.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content.content));

        if(cleft.clientHeight > cright.clientHeight) {
            cright.appendChild(preview);
        } else {
            cleft.appendChild(preview);
        }
    };
}
```

The code above works as intended. The problem is, the posts are saved on the blog's database, and I don't know how to retrieve them from the database so I could use the posts' data on Javascript. Been looking for a way (with no results) to create a list of the to-be-shown posts on the view code, and use such list on JavaScript. I'm using Django, by the way.

Comment: First, I tried to pass just a list of the posts to the template (something like Posts.objects.all()) and then use it from javascript, to no avail. I tried to pass it to the template as json as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side, I'd put all the posts in order without trying to put them in two columns. Then on the client side you can have JavaScript deal with laying out the posts into two columns.

For example, you have the Django template output something like this:

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="post">...</div>
    <div class="post">...</div>
    <div class="post">...</div>
    <div class="post">...</div>
</div>
```

In the JavaScript, on page load, you can take all of the posts out of `#posts` and create the columns and arrange the posts into the columns as you want:

```
// First, retrieve our element containing all the posts:
var posts = document.getElementById('posts');

// Then, create the columns we want to put the posts into:
var leftColumn = document.createElement('div');
var rightColumn = document.createElement('div');
// You'll probably want to give them IDs or classes so you can style them.

// Next, we'll replace the #posts div with the two columns:
posts.parentNode.insertBefore(leftColumn, posts);
posts.parentNode.insertBefore(rightColumn, posts);
posts.parentNode.removeChild(posts);

// Now we have two empty columns on the page and the original #posts div stored
// within the posts variable.  We can now take elements out of the #posts div and
// place them into the columns.

while(posts.hasChildNodes()) {
    // Fetch the next element from the #posts div and remove it.
    var post = posts.firstChild;
    posts.removeChild(post);
    // We might catch some whitespace here; if so, discard it and move on.
    if(post.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        continue;
    }
    // Put the post in one of the columns, based on your logic.
    // (I think you can figure this out, based on the code in your question.)
}
```

Comment: The posts are ordered and coming from the server already. The problem is, I need (or at least I think I need) to use javascript to display them properly, and I don't seem to be able to manipulate django variables from javascript properly.

Comment: @Daniel: JavaScript doesn't need to modify the server-side variables; it can just rearrange the elements on the client side. I'll edit my answer to clarify a bit more, perhaps.

Comment: My reply to your answer wasn't clear either, sorry. By manipulating the variables, I meant I'm not able to even get their values!

Comment: @Valbrand: My suggestion was that on the server-side, you output it as if you had only one column, but then have JavaScript deal with rearranging the one column into two columns. I've added some concrete code to my answer that might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, now I got what you meant. Saved me from a lot of hassle!